# How do I get the user object so I can get their username?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I store discord id's of user's in my database. For example `644163463064846347` as a BIGINT.
However, when I try to get the user object, it returns me `None`. How can I fix this. I do not have access to the context as this is not a command. Just the client itself. Code in my cogs:

```
async def test_function(self, discordId):
    pos1User = self.client.get_user(discordId)
    return pos1User.name + "#" +pos1User.discriminator
```

Comment: What is the python type when you check `type(discordId)`? Have you tried `pos1User = self.client.get_user(int(discordId))`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure where/when you're running this in your code, but perhaps doing this will help:

```py
async def test_function(self, discordId: int): # define type to make sure you're passing in an int
    await self.client.wait_until_ready()
    pos1User = self.client.get_user(discordId)
    return str(pos1User) # equivalent to the method you used for returning "name#1234"
```

Doing this will ensure that the client's internal cache is ready before you try to use or access it. The issue could have been that you were trying to find a user, but due to the cache not being ready yet, it returned None, as it wasn't able to find it.

---

**References:**

- [`Client.wait_until_ready()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_until_ready)
- [`discord.User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User) (specifically, `str(x)`)